# Joining to a table with multiple entries for just one record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `geo`.

I am joining to this table like so -

```
JOIN geo ON other_table.county_geoid = geo.geoid
```

This is sample data in the table -

```
id  type    state  county       stcode  county_code geoid
539 COUNTY  CA     Los Angeles  05      210         06037
538 COUNTY  CA     Los Angeles  05      200         06037
520 COUNTY  CA     Alameda      05      000         06001
```

How do I join to this table so records where the county is `Los Angeles` aren't counted twice?

Comment: There must be two entries for LA in one of the tables. Show us the sample data, and query that you are trying. I can see country_code is different for LA rows.

Comment: why LA county has two code?

Answer (score 0):

In the sample data you included, the county_code is different.  A "group by" sql clause will collapse columns based on all non-aggregated fields.  So, as long as there is a different field value, in this case the county_code field, then both records will be shown.  If you exclude the county_code field in the select statement, then a "group by" clause at the end of the query will collapse the two records and return only a single record.

```
/* Exclude county_code */
select geo.type, state, county, stcode, geo.geoid
from   other_table
       JOIN geo 
            ON other_table.county_geoid = geo.geoid
group by type, state, county, stcode, geoid
```

If, you were counting or doing any aggregation such as the first example below, then a temp table would allow you to reduce the count aggregation.  The temp table version is the second example below.

```
/* Exclude county_code */
select geo.type, state, county, stcode, geo.geoid, count(*)
from   other_table
       JOIN geo 
            ON other_table.county_geoid = geo.geoid
group by type, state, county, stcode, geoid
```

The temp table version would be:

```
/* Exclude county_code */
select geo.type, state, county, stcode, geo.geoid
into #temp
from   other_table
       JOIN geo 
            ON other_table.county_geoid = geo.geoid
group by type, state, county, stcode, geoid

Select t.type, t.state, t.county, t.stcode, t.geoid, count(*) as "RowCount"
from #temp t
group by type, state, county, stcode, geoid
```